# Cannot set property 'session' of undefined

Tags: node.js, session

trying to create shopping cart,
For that I'm try to make use Session mongoose.

In this line of code:

```
req.locals.session = req.session;
```

The error is

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'session' of undefined

Here is my code:
https://codepaste.net/gr7pmi

Comment: I found the problem NO REQ -> res

Comment: What was the problem ? You have to use res.locals right ? that's good practise and official one too.